# How to parse GZIP compressed header while requesting through Rest Template in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gzip, resttemplate

I'm trying to send gzip compressed request through REST Template.

My Request Format:-

```
url = apiUrl + mymethod + "?api_key=" + apiKey;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("api_key", apiKey);
            headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "x-gzip");

            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",
                    headers);
            ResponseEntity<GenericResponseDto> response = null;

            try {
                response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                        GenericResponseDto.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CustomException(e, aPIAuditTrail);
            }
            log.info("Response :"+response);
```

While sending this request getting response message like :-`"Response(code=401, message=gzip not passed as header parameters)"`

If i change the request header to

```
headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

i'm getting exception like : -

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1eb7b683; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1eb7b683; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:835)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
    at com.finateltech.api.newbitla.service.AvailabilitiesService.onDemandsearch(AvailabilitiesService.java:222)
    at com.finateltech.api.newbitla.service.AvailabilitiesService.search(AvailabilitiesService.java:182)
    at com.finateltech.api.newbitla.service.AvailabilitiesService.process(AvailabilitiesService.java:386)
    at com.finateltech.api.bitla.processor.BitlaRequestProcessor.process(BitlaRequestProcessor.java:70)
    at com.finateltech.api.bitla.processor.BitlaRequestListener.onMessage(BitlaRequestListener.java:39)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1eb7b683; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:484)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2875)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:692)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3776)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2810)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:226)
    ... 23 more
```

Also tried with adding below propeties application.prperties file

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,application/javascript,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

nothing changed same Error message like

```
"Response(code=401, message=gzip not passed as header parameters)"
```

My Spring boot Version is 1.3.5.RELEASE.

Please help me how to send compressed gzip request in spring boot?